# editable JCombobox that filters the list and show only text that contains the text I wrote

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

I need to have an editable `JCombobox` that contains elements : example:

```
element 1
element 2
item one
item one two
element item
```

And when I write for example "one", It have to show me only

```
item one
item one two
```

All I found before are `AutocompleteJCombobox` which scrolls me to the items that starts with "one".

thank you in advance

Comment: Use e.g. http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html replacing s.indexOf(value) == 0 with s.indexOf(value) >=0

Comment: Thank you!!!! Finallyyyy it worked !! Put you comment as an answer to mark it as a correct answer ... you really saved my time :D:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.g. algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html replacing `s.indexOf(value) == 0` with `s.indexOf(value) >=0`

defining a searchable data structure:

```
public interface Searchable<E, V>{
    public Collection<E> search(V value);
}
```

basic demonstration:

```
public class StringSearchable implements Searchable<String,String>{

    private List<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();

    public StringSearchable(List<String> terms){
        this.terms.addAll(terms);
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<String> search(String value) {
        List<String> founds = new ArrayList<String>();

        for ( String s : terms ){
            if ( s.indexOf(value) == 0 ){
                founds.add(s);
            }
        }
        return founds;
    }
}
```

Now for the JComboBox auto-completion:

```
public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 4321421L;
    private final Searchable<String,String> searchable;

    public AutocompleteJComboBox(Searchable<String,String> s){
        super();
        this.searchable = s;
        setEditable(true);
        Component c = getEditor().getEditorComponent();

        if ( c instanceof JTextComponent ){
            final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent)c;
            tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                    update();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                    update();
                }

                public void update(){
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            List<String> founds = new ArrayList<String>(searchable.search(tc.getText()));
                            Set<String> foundSet = new HashSet<String>();
                            for ( String s : founds ){
                                foundSet.add(s.toLowerCase());
                            }
                            Collections.sort(founds);//sort alphabetically
                            setEditable(false);
                            removeAllItems();
                            //if founds contains the search text, then only add once.

                            if ( !foundSet.contains( tc.getText().toLowerCase()) ){
                                addItem( tc.getText() );
                            }                           

                            for (String s : founds) {
                                addItem(s);
                            }
                            setEditable(true);
                            setPopupVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            tc.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    if ( tc.getText().length() > 0 ){
                        setPopupVisible(true);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {                        
                }
            });
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Editing component is not a JTextComponent!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to add an object instead of String. For example class : Status{int id; String name} and I need to search the name and on select it will select the object. What do I have to do ? Is there a simple way

Comment: Override toString() of the class to return text to be shown in the JCombBox

Comment: This produces strange ComboBox. No options/items are listed at runtime. Only when you start typing, do elements start showing up. Users are expected to fully know the invisible options, then they are expected to type in instead of just choosing a visible item and type ONLY IF option is somewhere down the whole lot :(

Answer (score 0):

StanislavL's AutocompleteJComboBox looses focus while typing when used with other components in the same Window (at least in my case).
There is an easy fix though - add a requestFocus(); at the end of the run function.

Code with the addition:

```
public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox{
static final long serialVersionUID = 4321421L;
private final Searchable<String,String> searchable;

public AutocompleteJComboBox(Searchable<String,String> s){
    super();
    this.searchable = s;
    setEditable(true);
    Component c = getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    if ( c instanceof JTextComponent ){
        final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent)c;
        tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                update();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                update();
            }

            public void update(){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        List<String> founds = new ArrayList<String>(searchable.search(tc.getText()));
                        Set<String> foundSet = new HashSet<String>();
                        for ( String s : founds ){
                            foundSet.add(s.toLowerCase());
                        }
                        Collections.sort(founds);//sort alphabetically
                        setEditable(false);
                        removeAllItems();
                        //if founds contains the search text, then only add once.

                        if ( !foundSet.contains( tc.getText().toLowerCase()) ){
                            addItem( tc.getText() );
                        }                           

                        for (String s : founds) {
                            addItem(s);
                        }
                        setEditable(true);
                        setPopupVisible(true);
                        requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        tc.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if ( tc.getText().length() > 0 ){
                    setPopupVisible(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {                        
            }
        });
    }else{
        throw new IllegalStateException("Editing component is not a JTextComponent!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This comes with the drawback that requestFocus() selects the whole text and as soon as you type the next char, previous one is over-written. Overall this comboBox is a pain for the user...